# Is this good practice to use out-of-scope variable in Python?

Tags: python

```
def test_scope():    
    i = 0
    while(i<3):
        j = i
        i += 1
    
    print (j)
```

I saw other's code like this. j only exists in the while scope, but it seems valid in Python. In PyCharm, it gives a warning that 'j' can be undefined, but it doesn't throw an error. I likes to define the 'j' with some initial value before the while loop.

Is this good practice in Python using an out-of-scope variable?

Comment: Python doesn't have block scoped variables.

Comment: Is everything top-level code (bad idea anyway), or inside a function?  Note that if the first four lines are inside one function, and the `j` is elsewhere, you won't be modifying the same `j`.

Comment: If the loop never runs, `j` will never be assigned. That's what Pycharm is warning you about. This has nothing to do with scope.\

Comment: @FrankYellin It's inside a function, but I am not used to let j be accessible outside of a loop.

Comment: Then you need to broaden your horizon. It's quite common to set variables inside a loop and use them after. How else will you get information from the loop?

Comment: In that case, I'm perfectly happy with this code.  I have no problem with loops setting variables outside the loop.  This is a common practice.

Comment: @FrankYellin,  but it's annoying that PyCharm highlights it as yellow text: "local reference might be referenced before assignment. " Why not initialize the 'j' to some sensible value before the while loop, as other languages do?